# android rotating screen causes text colour to change to default

Tags: java, android, configuration

In my android app where I am creating a tic tac toe game, I have this code below where if it's player one move then set their selection as **X** with a particular colour, else it must be player 2 so set text as **O** for their selection with a different colour.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
        return;
    }

    if (playerOneMove) {
        ((Button) v).setText("X");
        ((Button) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e8e5e5"));
    } else {
        ((Button) v).setText("O");
        ((Button) v).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#737374"));
    } 

    ...

}
```

I have a problem though and it is in regards to when I rotate the screen. When I rotate the screen, the text for X and O both change to the default text colour android studio provides. I want to keep the colours for these text but I am not sure how to do that? I have made sure there is no global text colour set.

Below is my code that handles orientation changes:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("playerOneMove", playerOneMove);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    playerOneMove = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("playerOneMove");
}
```

Comment: Try using a color from a color resource. Use an xml color file then set your color using `((Button) v).setTextColor(R.color.your_color)`

Comment: @SystemGlitch I've set the colours as you have said but still problem persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the colours of each box of your tic tac toe board and retain them again on your layout configuration changes (i.e. device rotation).

You might consider looking into the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096580/how-to-save-the-fields-data-while-changing-the-layout-on-screen-rotation) for a detailed explanation of your problem. You might check the [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange) here for handling the configuration changes as well.

The key idea is to save the layout statues in variables which survives the configuration changes and update them accordingly in your `onCreate` or `onCreateView` function in case of `Activity` and `Fragment` respectively. However, in your case, you need to store a lot of data and on each configuration change, you need to restore them again which is not an efficient way to do that. I would like to recommend you look for other available options which survive the orientation or configuration changes of your layout.

I would strongly suggest implementing [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel) in your case, which survives the application configuration change and handles the overall UI representation in the most effective way. The idea is to bind your UI elements with your `ViewModel` and then retain the UI elements each time from your `ViewModel`. It can be retained at the exact state until the `Activity` or `Fragment` finishes.

In your case, I would like to provide an example of how you can prepare a `ViewModel`. Let us consider your `ViewModel` is `GameModel` which saves the layout items of your board.

```
public class GameModel extends ViewModel {
     public final LiveData<Game> gameLiveData = new LiveData<>();

     public GameModel() {
         // trigger game load.
     }

     void doAction() {
         // depending on the action, do necessary business logic calls and update the gameLiveData.
     }
}

public class Game {
    public static final int CROSS = 1; 
    public static final int ZERO = 0;

    public int pos1 = -1; // Default values are -1, when the position is yet to be played
    public int pos2 = -1;
    public int pos3 = -1;
    public int pos4 = -1;
    public int pos5 = -1;
    public int pos6 = -1;
    public int pos7 = -1;
    public int pos8 = -1;
    public int pos9 = -1;
}
```

Now from your `Activity`, you need to add an observer to your `GameModel` class to update the UI accordingly.

```
public class UserActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.game_activity_layout);
         final GameModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GameModel.class);
         viewModel.gameLiveData.observer(this, new Observer() {
            @Override
             public void onChanged(@Nullable Game gameData) {
                 // update ui.
             }
         });
         findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Pass parameters in doAction function to set the items in the Game class and update the ui accordingly inside the onChanged function.
                  viewModel.doAction(); 
             }
         });
     }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cool I will keep that for note for my next app I build. As for a quick fix on keeping the colours what will I need to add in my code? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Is there a way I can call on my buttons to place in my save instance and restore instance?

Comment: As referenced in my answer, you might check this [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39097782/3145960) on how you are going to save the data along with instance state. Hope that helps!

Comment: What I should have said is how can I call on the buttons in the saved instance, thats the part I am struggling on. I want to store the x and o already selected in my onsaveinstance and onrestore but not sure how to call on it?

Comment: I would suggest you have a `Game` class saving the actions performed on your tic-tac-toe board. Based on that you will re-instantiate the board.

Comment: And I would suggest strongly on keeping an observer using `ViewModel`. Believe me, this is not too much work for now. It will save time in future.

Comment: Cool Reaz, I will do that then, Thank you very much :)